# Low quality answer review. Skip button vs Looks okay button

Tags: discussion, review-queues

When reviewing low quality answers, often someone else has added a constructive comment prompting the responder to improve their answer.

- Should I hit "looks okay" to clear it from the queue and give the suggestion some time, or should I hit "skip" to keep it in the queue?
- How long should these comments be given before reflagging the answer (if dropped from the queue) or recommending deletion?

Comment: You may upvote the *constructive comment* to let more users notice it. Do not hit "looks okay" until the post has been edited to improve. Because if many users select "looks okay", it will survive the review and stay as VLQ.

Comment: I rarely saw posters respond to a constructive comment. Sometimes, I edit the post myself it it requires a link and its essential part and upvote it. If it attracts upvotes, it will be removed from a review queue (I am not 100% sure how it works). I think the most important thing is whether the answer is considered to be low quality at the time you review it. If I find it low-quality, I never hesitate to click on "recommend deletion". 9 out of 10, the poster will never come back especially when the poster is new (1 rep or 101 rep).

Comment: The VLQ answers are usually hopeless, substantively.

Comment: Now that I've upvoted a comment, I see that it opens up the "I'm Done" button. That helps quite a bit.

Comment: I think you reviewed "First Post", not "Low Quality Post". They have different buttons and "I am done" doesn't appear on "Low Quality Post review". :-) When you review "First Post", you can leave a comment or upvote an existing comment and click on "I'm done".

Answer (score 5):

> Should I hit "looks okay" to clear it from the queue and give the suggestion some time, or should I hit "skip" to keep it in the queue?

**You be the judge.**

Review process takes a while. If the OP returns to edit, click "looks okay". Else, "recommend deletion". "Skip" delays the review process, until someone else attends to it.

I, personally, would leave a comment or upvote others' and still "recommend deletion" if:

- I can't improve it myself
- I think that the OP is gone for a very long time.

> How long should these comments be given before reflagging the answer (if dropped from the queue) or recommending deletion?

**Again, you decide.**

I would have flagged it instantly. It's debatable.